# REST, getting additional information for an SPA

Tags: rest

I'm trying to understand this from a REST theoretical perspective.

You have a book collection, it's an entity you can get, delete, etc.

You have an individual book, you get it with an id, delete it with an id, etc

You have an Angular app where you can add new books. So you get the book collection, add a book locally, haven't sent it to the server yet

You need additional info on the book before you add it, for example you need to know if there are any other books with the same title

Can you have multiple GET calls in a RESTful architecture for the same entity? i.e. one with id and another with a name? So you could try to GET the book with the name to see if it already exists

Where does 'get additional info for an as of yet uncreated entity' fit into this? Lets say you need an image for the book and you have stock images, I'm assuming that the images are entities in and of themselves so they have their own REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you basically want to do a search on some criteria (name, etc) to check that the book does not already exist. You can use GET for book which would not include id as a path variable but would include the criteria filter params as request parameters(query string). Something like this:

```
/book?name=bookname --   List book with name as bookname
/book/{id}          --   List book with given id
```

Multiple GET calls for the same entity is not encouraged in a RESTful architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you have multiple GET calls in a RESTful architecture for the same entity?

Jim Webber: You should expect to have many many more resources in your integration domain than you do business objects in your business domain.

So sure, why not?  How could the client possibly know?

> Where does 'get additional info for an as of yet uncreated entity' fit into this?

When in doubt, try to envision what you are doing as a web page.  Would be be reasonable to send to ask the web server for a form to add a new book with a particular title, and have it return the form, a list of known books with similar titles, a set of stock images, etc?  Of course.  So it's going to be fine for your API to do the same thing.

Or perhaps the form should be a separate idea, and the search results should look like a link to the form, and a bunch of links to representations of existing books.  That's also fine.

Using links from unstable things to stable things is often a good idea, because it affords caching.